# Not getting into the callback url

Tags: asp.net

I am using oauth in my web application to access Twitter. My problem is i am not getting the token secret and moreover when i run my application it asks the user for authorization request. when the user click "allow', it does not go back to the called url. Infact it shows a blank untitled page with a url having oauth _token value and oauth_verifier value.
Can someone throw light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Before you send users to twitter.com to authorized the app you need to save the request token secret. When the users clicks allow they will return to the callback url you specify. Once there you need to use the request token/secret to get an access token from twitter that will let you perform API requests as a user.

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/oauth/access_token